# jQuery UI dialog title area gets stretched out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-dialog

In the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/8Lhns/ if you click on any of the links (like `View Uploads`) the title bar of the jQuery dialog gets stretched.

**BUT** when you look at the same page in regular view http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/8Lhns/show/ and then click on a link, the dialog box looks normal (if the browser is maximized, if the browser is **not** maximized, you have the same issue).

How do I fix it so that the dialog box looks normal no matter what?

Comment: It pops back to normal when you adjust the size of it too, strange.

Comment: @Jack -- yea, i know its very very weird. I added some css to it, but im not sure why it worked (added it as an answer).....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `float: left;` on your `#content`

Comment: Then the rest of the css gets messed up. also why would that affect a random div?

Comment: see here for full answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276884/jquery-ui-dialog-title-area-gets-stretched-out/7277170#7277170

Answer (score 1):

Just add this CSS style to your stylesheet:

```
.ui-dialog { clear: both; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was as @Interstellar_Coder stated about `float: left`

I solved by adding to the `div` after it is a dialog:

```
        var widg = div.dialog('widget');
        widg.css('clear','both');
```

This solved the issue, but it is really a hack. The css of the page should have been made better in general.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/8Lhns/15/